# Facebook Graph Api pagination not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have been trying to retrieve the wall feed of a facebook user using the graph api with the url **https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN** where ACCESS_TOKEN is the access_token used for querying.

The first query, i.e using the above url works fine, but it shows only few latest feeds from the user's wall. To get the next feeds, the url contained in the **[next]**  field of the json array returned is to be used(as mentioned in the facebook documentation). Earlier it worked fine, but from last few days it just shows an Empty array.

Any Help Appreciated!